# how to record login date which members login by remember me?

Tags: yii

i can record the last login time with authenticate function in useridentity.php if member login by using login form. But i couldnt record the last login date if member login by remember me cookies. are there any ways to record?

```
$logindate = UserAccount::model()->findbypk($member->id);
$logindate->last_login_date = date('Y-m-d');
$logindate->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do that in a custom web user component that extends from `CWebUser`. Then you can override [`afterLogin()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#afterLogin-detail) there and store the login date even for cookie logins.